# Where does Guardians of the Galaxy fit into the MCU timeline?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, chronology, guardians-of-the-galaxy

The film starts in 1988, this much we know.

When Yondu points out that he made sure his crew didn't eat Peter, Quill remarks that "For Twenty years you've been throwing that back in my face!"

If we're to take this literally, it means the film is set in 2008: the same time as the events of *Iron Man* are unfolding on Earth...

The Collector doesn't appear to be in possession of the Aether from *Thor: the Dark World*, so we're probably supposed to believe this film happened before the events of that...

...BUT, although uncredited, his assistant Carina is still alive in T:TDW, played by the same actress (Ophelia Lovibond). Does this mean the events of GotG happened *after* T:TDW? if this is the case, does the collector still possess the Aether?

None of the MCU timelines [seem to](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline) [include](http://www.tiki-toki.com/timeline/entry/5395/A-Marvel-Cinematic-Universe-Timeline) GotG, so I'm struggling to place it chronologically..

Comment: Putting this as a comment rather than an answer because I can't find the link where I read this... But the Marvel movies (unless another year is specified) take place in real time relative to each other. So if marvel movie B comes out after marvel movie A, it is established that the events in A already took place when you're watching B

Comment: I have corrected myself :).  Really well done timeline placing all marvel events can be found here:  http://www.tiki-toki.com/timeline/entry/5395/A-Marvel-Cinematic-Universe-Timeline

Comment: @WizardKnight, according to *Fury's Big Week*, the events of *The Incredible Hulk* (released 2008) occur within the same week as *Iron Man 2* (released 2010), so they can't be **relative** to each other, exactly... also, the link you post is already embedded within the question...

Comment: I didn't see that it was embedded. I posted it to correct my incorrect comment :)

Comment: By the looks of collectors he seems angry in T:DW like he lost once and won't lose again and his expression in GotG shows that he is seeing the stone for the first time so according to me GotG is before T:DW

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As you say, the film starts in 1988:

[image: 1988]

Then, right after the Marvel logo:

[image: 26 years later]

**So, it takes place in 2014**.

---

Marvel has also [published](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/marvel-releases-digital-guardians-galaxy-693045) a [prequel comic](http://www.guardthegalaxy.com/2014/04/what-we-learned-from-guardians-of.html), that establishes that **GotG** takes place *after* The Collector receives the Aether.

[image: Comic]

Comment: P.S.: __[Why was Ronan/Thanos not interested in the other Infinity Stone in possession of The Collector?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/24346/why-was-ronan-thanos-not-interested-in-the-other-infinity-stone-in-possession-of)__

Comment: fantastic spot! well done. So Quill's twenty years was just a generalisation!

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional Or Yondu waited six years before he started "throwing it in" Quill's face.

Answer (score 3):

In this [all-too-detailed layout](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline), the events in GotG begin to happen on August 1, 2014.  This is just a short time after the events of T:TDW and CA:TWS.

Comment: yup, that site was linked in my question. That's just a Wiki, and someone has simply 'decided' it takes place at the same time as the film was released... it doesn't address the inconsistency in my question... we have two indicators that the film is set before T:TDW, and one stating it happens afterwards

Comment: Actually, it wasn't linked in your question, unless I'm missing something.  Your question linked to tiki-toki.

Comment: @JohnnyBones There were two different links next to each other (which is why I usually let a non-linked word as separator in this case).

Comment: Ah HA!  My bad.  :o)